# Windows 10 not detecting Samsung 840 Pro SSD

Tags: ssd, windows-10-preview

I just got Samsung 840 Pro SSD, but my Windows 10 is not detecting it. Any idea what I should do?

I tried using the Samsung utility mentioned on their website at http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html
but the software does not detect it and neither does Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with 840 pro.  I contacted Samsung about it, and their response was to use windows 7 or 8.1

I wish I could be more help, but they haven't released compatible software yet.

Answer (score 1):

I went around these problems a lot of times, trying different cables, boxes and bios configurations.

In the end, I found that http://www.easeus.com/backup-software/tb-free.html fixed the problem - just ignore the Samsung software until it works with Windows 10.

Run EasyUS and select disk clone, select the source drive/volume (usually 0) and destination (could be 1, 2 or 3 depending on whether you have a cdrom and other drives installed).  Please note I did a sector by sector copy (may not have been necessary, but I wanted to make sure it worked).

The EasyUS clone takes place regardless of the fact you are running a new version of Windows or using a USB to SATA controller that is not supported by the Samsung software. Just make sure you choose the right disks (don't erase your C drive with a blank SSD!)

For Windows 10, I found that in addition to this I had to make sure my BIOS was set to force AHCI mode - just making it optional didn't work.

So far this has worked on Samsung Chronus and Sony Vaio laptops (mine and my wife's).

ps - I have absolutely nothing to do with this company, I just got fed up with waiting for a version of Magician or Data Migration that worked all of the time (and the above software works free, although I suspect the paid version might be quicker)

Comment: Yes, of course!   Both Samsung Magician and Samsung Data Migration require a genuine Samsung SSD, but the software was written for earlier versions of windows and also a USB to SATA cable that adds  not bells or whistles.  Users often want to clone their hard drive onto the SSD, only to be told by the Samsung software that their drive is not recognized.

Comment: Easeus.com backup has a disk clone function that is Windows 10 (and down) compatible, and does not care what sort of drive is being cloned from and to.  So when you say do a sector by sector clone from say drive 0 (C) to drive 2 (SSD) then the clone takes place regardless of the fact you are running a new version of Windows or using a USB to SATA controller that is not supported by the Samsung software.  Just make sure you choose the right disks (don't erase your C drive with a blank SSD!)

Comment: All done Twisty! Agree comments can be deleted or missed!

Answer (score 0):

Open `cmd.exe` as admin - write `diskpart` and then enter `list disk`.

Do you see your drive? Also check if you have SATA port enabled in BIOS.

You might also try a live Linux distribution; Ubuntu 15.04 for example if you can see your drive there.